How can I mount a PCB to a flexible housing?
I am working on a heating pad with a flexible housing so that it can wrap around parts of the body in certain ways. My PCB will be a normal rigid board, but the housing will resemble a silicone ice cube tray. The pad will be moved around and flexed so I need the board to stay still, but I am not sure that I will be able to tap holes for screws.
My first thought is to leave mounting holes on the PCB and make solid, unthreaded, bosses on the housing. Hopefully I can just press the board into it and get a secure fit that way.
Does anyone have any other ideas? This will need to be a permanent fixture that can be manhandled a little and even flipped upside down.
EDIT: I have included a (very) rough drawing of how the pad will look. If I had any actual pictures to show I would.
The PCBs are the heating element and also prevent the pad from flexing in the other direction.
The actual material will be a flexible PVC, but it will have a similar feel to a silicone ice tray.


I don't quite understand the question - some picture or sketch would be good.

I'm getting the impression that the PCBs themselves are the heating elements. As such, don't you want fairly intimate contact between them and the silicone housing?

@DaveTweed Yes, that is what I am trying to do.

@Lundin I added a quick picture. I hope it helps, the green bars are the PCBs

You know you can get pre-made silicone heat pads, right? Flexible heating elements encased in silicone such that they are completely bendable with just flying leads

The most logical solution is to make a flexible PCB. As long as the components used on it are not too big, there shouldn't be any major issues with components coming loose due to warping. YMMV though. Without knowing exactly how much flex is expected, a rigid board might still be doable.

The housing is pretty much one big rectangle with long pcbs going vertically. The pad needs flex width wise and stay somewhat rigid lengthwise. The boards should be able to provide enough support to allow this to happen, therefore I cannot use a flexible pcb for this project

Then I would recommend making a thin PCB (0.6 or 0.8 mm in thickness) and mounting it with rubber pads and maybe glue. But that is just my 2 cents, maybe someone else has a better idea.

The best way I can think of would be to place the silicon between two rigid parts, and screw them together until the silicon is squeezed enough that it stays there. Maybe some holes in the silicon itself for the screw to pass through, though I think that might tear after it rubs against the screw for some time.
One part can be the PCB itself, then you just need to make a bunch of small plates with holes, screws and nuts.
